# Restore Error: Could not upgrade the metadata

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore, change-data-capture

I am trying to restore a database from a Prod environment (11.0.6020.0) to a lower environment server (11.0.3128.0).  I realize the lower has an older SP, we are working on correcting that now.  The restore should still work though, it has for months, but I'm getting the following error message.  We just recently enabled this database for CDC, I'm not specifying keep_cdc in the restore.  Anybody seen this error before and know how to resolve it?

> Msg 22841, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_vupgrade, Line 320
>   [Batch Start Line 0] Could not upgrade the metadata for database
>   'DBName' that is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred
>   when executing the action 'alter cdc.change_tables index
>   change_tables_unique_idx with (drop_existing = on)'. The error
>   returned was 4922: 'line 102, state 9, ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN
>   column_id failed because one or more objects access this column.'. Use
>   the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and
>   resubmit the request.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] 
FROM  DISK = @FileToRestore WITH  
MOVE  'DBName' to 'W:\Data\DBName\DBName.mdf',
MOVE  'AmexDB_log' to 'W:\Logs\DBName\DBName_Log.ldf',
NOUNLOAD, REPLACE , FILE = 1, STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Is the lower environment Enterprise Edition too?

Comment: Yes, it is running Enterprise as well.

Comment: Did you try this solution on prod? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2009/11/19/could-not-update-the-metadata-that-indicates-database-is-enabled-for-change-data-capture-the-failure-occurred-when-executing-the-command-setcdctrackedvalue-1/

Comment: We were able to clear all the devs off of that server and are installing SP3 now, we shall see soon if that fixes it.  Still seems like an error that shouldn't occur though.

Comment: I checked and SA was already the owner in production.  The upgrade finished and that error went away.  I'm wondering if during the restore CDC is restored, then dropped if keep_cdc is not used.

Comment: Not sure, but glad you got it fixed. You should answer your own question, mark it as answered, so that others can find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve the issue by upgrading the lower environment to SP3.  Once that was done the restore completed without any errors.